# Utilizing Multiple USB 3.0 Ports for USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode

Tags: usb, display, hardware, port

I'm currently exploring the possibility of leveraging multiple USB 3.0 ports to collectively emulate USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode for connecting an external monitor.

Is it technically feasible to aggregate the capabilities of multiple USB 3.0 ports to mimic USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode?

If possible, what hardware and software would I need?

Comment: Are all of the USB-C ports 3.0 and how many are there? It might be dependent on video bandwidth of the host.

Comment: Three USB-A 3.0 and one USB-C @C__

Comment: Understood. So USB-A does not have the same data lines as USB-C to negotiate an alt mode equivalent. What I would recommend, however, is a protocol conversion, perhaps a bridge device. I actually have an 2x HDMI female to 1x USB-A 3.0. The blackbox likely has firmware that allows negotiation between host and the USB device.

Comment: Alt mode connects the USB cable wires to a DP output on the host, essentially it turns the cable into a DP cable. It's not clear what you mean by emulate, but you would need a DP output at least. If you don't have that, look for a USB video card or better yet PCIe.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not feasible, because in DP Alt Mode, the DP port of some video output is switched to the connector pins. Depending on what kind of link or adapter there is, you might have two USB3 SS lanes and two DP lanes during Alt Mode connection.

So no matter how many USB3 connectors you have, they speak USB3 protocol and cannot be used for DisplayPort.

If you want, you could build a device (a box) with a bunch of chips, and it might take one USB3 port and one DP port from your PC and then provide a Type-C port which supports Alt Mode.

Comment: I've seen on amazon adapters that claim to convert USB-A 2.0/3.0 to HDMI. https://www.amazon.com/-/en/Manhattan-Adaptador-convierte-f%C3%A1cilmente-151061/dp/B006VYWIVI how do you think they're going about it?

Comment: @LewisTrem That's a completely different thing then. That is basically a slow/simple GPU with HDMI output that happens to connect to PC via USB. It does not "convert" anything in the sense you might call a conversion. USB3 is a data link for transferring data, not a video link for transferring video.